# Estimation of a time in a random walk

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-walk

I have a discrete times birth and death process $\{\Psi_n\}_{n\in \mathbb N}$ with birth probability $p$ and death probability $q$ defined as follows:
\begin{align}
\Psi_n=\sum_{i=1}^n\eta_i
\end{align}
where $\{\eta_i\}_{i\in\mathbb N}$ is a family of random variables i.i.d. such that
\begin{align}
\eta_i=
\begin{cases}
1,\; &p\\
-1, \; &q\\
\end{cases}
\end{align}
and such that $\Psi_0=1$. Call
\begin{align}
V_N=\min\{n\geq 0: \Psi_n\geq N^{\frac{1}{10}}\}
\end{align}

I need to prove that 
\begin{align}\label{p}
\lim_{N\to +\infty}\mathbb P({V_{N}\leq N^{\frac{2}{10}}})=1
\end{align}

My idea is to apply the law of large numbers.
From the law of large numbers I know that
\begin{align}
\frac{\Psi_{N^{\frac{2}{10}}}}{(p-q)N^{\frac{2}{10}}}\xrightarrow[N\to+\infty]{}1 
\end{align}
almost surely. Then, this allows me to conclude that
\begin{align}
\frac{\Psi_{N^{\frac{2}{10}}}}{N^{\frac{1}{10}}}\xrightarrow[N\to+\infty]{}+\infty 
\end{align}
and consequently

$$\mathbb P(\Psi_{N^{\frac{2}{10}}}\geq N^{1/10})\xrightarrow[N\to +\infty]{} 1$$.
This finally implies that
\begin{align}
\lim_{N\to +\infty}\mathbb P({V_{N}\leq N^{\frac{2}{10}}})=1
\end{align}

Is that correct in your opinion?

Comment: What if $p\leq q$?  For example if $p<q$ then $P[V_N=\infty] \geq P[V_2=\infty] >0$ for all $N \in \{2, 3, 4, ...\}$.  So the thing you are trying to prove is false.

Comment: For the case $p>q$ your proof looks like it is going in a good direction, but a few modifications are needed, such as taking care of ceiling/floor issues on non-integer indices, and justifying your claims more clearly by noting, for example $$\{\Psi_{\lfloor N^{2/10}\rfloor}\geq N^{1/10}\} \subseteq \{V_N \leq N^{2/10}\}$$